# stl map.find perform differently in debug and release using vs2010

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I am using stl map to store flow information extracted from pcap files. When a packet comes, I use map.find to find if the flow the packet belongs to exist. I have to use map.find twice since the packet from A to B and the packet from B to A belongs to the same flow.

```
struct FiveTuple
{
unsigned short source_port;
unsigned short dest_port;
unsigned int source_ip_addr;
unsigned int dest_ip_addr;
unsigned char transport_proto_type;
};
```

The FiveTuple identifies a flow. I use the FiveTuple as the key element in map.

map is map< FiveTuple, Flow, FlowCmp>, where FlowCmp is a struct using memcmp to see if FiveTuple a is less than FiveTuple b, just like operator<.
To find whether the flow of the packet exists, I wrote code as follows where m is the name of the map and five_tuple is a FiveTuple with information extracted from the packet:

```
auto it = m.find(five_tuple);
if( it == m.end())
{
     //swap source and dest ip/port in five_tuple,
    it = m.find(five_tuple);

    if(it == m.end())
    {
          //do something
    }
}
```

In the debug version in vs2010, the result is reasonable. When I changed it to the release version, I found that instead of returning the right iterator, the second m.find just gave me m.end most of the time. And I found that there are no initialization problems. How to fix the release version problem?

Comment: Try adding `operator<` to your tuple struct. Just a guess.

Comment: @Naveen: Useless, since he passes an explicit comparator to map.

Comment: @Yihong Xiang: It is typical (and stupid...) for Debug builds to initialize the memory of objects/built-ins/etc... to `0`, which guarantees stability. However in Release such "helpful" 0-ing is removed since it's normally unnecessary...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you are doing memcmp() on FiveTuple objects. That is undefined behaviour because FiveTuple contains trailing garbage bytes. These trailing garbage bytes are different in the debug version and the release version, so you get different results. You should rewrite FlowCmp so that it doesn't use memcmp().

This is a guess based on the limited information provided, but if you want to test it out try `cout << sizeof(FiveTuple);`. I bet you'll see that `sizeof(FiveTuple) > sizeof(short) + sizeof(short) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(char)`. In other words there's garbage in your struct and you shouldn't use memcmp.

Of course memcmp is bad for another reason because it means your code will be non-portable because it's behaviour will depend on the **endianess** of your platform. That in itself is good enough reason not to use memcmp for this purpose.

Comment: With your answers, I use memset to initialize five_tuple to 0, and the result now seems to be correct, thank you.

Comment: OK, glad to help. But the arguments against memcmp still stand. It's non-portable.

Comment: Well， the endianess is not an issue since I have already transform the ip addresses and ports into my local endians before using map.find. Thanks again.

Comment: @john: I am guessing that here the order matters not, indeed, a hash function would have done as well.

Comment: @YihongXiang Is there a real reason for using `memcmp` here at all? It’s simply not a good idea, and certainly not necessary.